# Create Image file on another server

Tags: php

I have a php script on a shared server which create an image. Right now images are generated on local server. I want to create images on another server and save them there. Im using following code

```
$srcpng = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://ipaddressofserver/images/news.jpg');
imagecopy($srcpng, $src, 378, 0, 0, 0, 160, 160);                                   
$black = imagecolorallocate( $srcpng, 0, 0, 0 );   
foreach ($lines as $line)
 {
imagettftext($srcpng, $fontsize , 0, 22, $y, $black, $font, $line);

$y += 20;
 } 

 imagejpeg( $srcpng, "img/{$appname}/{$fbid}.jpg",$quality );
```

imagejpeg function is currently saving images on local server. 
source image file is there on another server.
allow_url_fopen is enabled

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274551/how-to-upload-image-to-another-server